# battery usage not showing in instruments for higher versions like iOS10

Tags: ios, performance, battery

When battery logs are imported to instruments, the logs show no value. Therefore we cannot collect battery utilization for iOS 10 or above. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

it's very strange.
you're running the latest version of XCode (8.2.1)? 
with an iPhone 10.2 works like a charm (clearly not works on simulator).